Default (browser) values of an HTML element (TABLE, TR and TD specifically) or how to override existing style to default?
We all know each browser doesn't have the same default values for HTML elements.
Also, if some CSS is already applied to some elements, can we override the particular element we want to default browser style (whatever it is)?
For example, all TRs have the same height value defined in CSS ( TR {height:50px} ), but what if I want to have the default value of TR's height for TR.defaultRow ( TR.defaultRow {height:**default**} )?
Also, how can I get the browser's default CSS value for an element?
currentStyle is not working anymore.
getComputedStyle are not default CSS values but calculated temporary values of an element.
For example, height is not auto or inherit but 23.44344px or something like that.
EDITED:
One more thing, how to have the exact behaviour of two or more elements of two or more table-cells?
For example, 2 TD elements will take 50% of available space, 3 TD elements will take 33,33% and so on.
And they will expand as content expands inside the TD element, that behaviour to an element too.

Browsers do not define a height for table rows in their user agent stylesheet to begin, so if you just want to go back to the "default" on that one, just use height: auto. For other stuff, look into https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/revert

This is exactly why you should be using a 'reset stylesheet'. Research that term to find some good examples

I remember a long time ago I had currentStyle, and I could see the default value (auto or inherited) of an HTML element so I was able to put the default value to a specific element. That is the idea. Some elements have auto, some inherit for HEIGHT property, it is changed to some value and I want to put default one back.

currentStyle was a non-standard IE thing. You can use property-name: revert to remove author styles from an element.

Alohci, thnx, but what if I put 'display:table-cell' to an DIV element, and put 'height:revert;width:revet', would it be DIV default value or table-cell default value?

@CBroe, if I put 'display:table-cell' to an DIV element, and put 'height:revert;width:revet', would it be DIV default value or table-cell default value?

That should be those the UA stylesheet applies for div then - because it is not very likely to apply a width and height based on the fact, that the div has display:table-cell set, to begin with. Unless you had a user stylesheet, that explicitly tried to do something like that (like, select the div via an attribute selector, that specifically targets display:table-cell set as inline style) ...?

If you don't provide any style for the specific element then they'll have the browser default style and as you said each browser has it's own default style. instead of providing default style for an element try to overwrite it by giving it another style. most of the default styles can be easily overwritten. but sometimes you have to find some other workarounds like wrapping that element inside a div or something and give that style. or parent elements like the table itself doesn't accept many styles cause they're just for accessibility and ...so you've to give the styles to child like rows and cells.
for the last part which u updated , do you mean you want something like a div and several elements inside it and give them same width and height? if it's what you mean then you've to use the grid.

this is not what i am looking for...i want default browser value of an property of an element...i remember IE had currentStyle or something like that where you could get default value, but not calculated (if width is 100% or auto or inherit, you will see it, not get exactly value in pixels like calculated value)
